# vba copy range from workbook and paste into email?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following VBA code to try and copy a range from a workbook and paste this into an email:

This is the piece of code causing the issue. Error 438 'object doesn't support this property or method' on this line:

```
WB3.Range("A20:J30").SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Code:

```
'Insert Range
Dim app As New Excel.Application
app.Visible = False
'open a workbook that has same name as the sheet name
Set WB3 = Workbooks.Open(Range("F" & i).value)
'select cell A1 on the target book
WB3.Range("A20:J30").SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)

Call stream.WriteText(rangetoHTML(rng))
```

If i use ThisWorkbook, seems to work fine. It's something wrong with how i am defining the other workbook.

My cells in column F all contain valid paths like:

```
G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\3. Confirmation and Delivery\Announcements\2017\test\Accrol.xlsx
```

Pleas can someone show me where i am going wrong? Ideally i would rather get the range from the workbook without having to open it, but alas i am brand new to vba so not sure if this would work.

The aim is to get the range put into the body of an email.

```
Call stream.WriteText(rangetoHTML(rng))
```

Full Code:

```
Sub Send()
Dim answer As Integer
    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Send All Announcements?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Notice")
    If answer = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub

    Else

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Attachment As String
Dim WB3 As Workbook
Dim WB4 As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
Dim db As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim body As Object
Dim header As Object
Dim stream As Object
Dim session As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim server, mailfile, user, usersig As String
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
LastRow = Worksheets(1).Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'Finds the last used row

j = 18

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

For i = 18 To LastRow


'Start a session of Lotus Notes
Set session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
'This line prompts for password of current ID noted in Notes.INI
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set stream = session.CreateStream
' Turn off auto conversion to rtf
session.ConvertMime = False



'Email Code

'Create email to be sent

Set doc = db.CreateDocument
doc.Form = "Memo"
Set body = doc.CreateMIMEEntity
Set header = body.CreateHeader("Promotion Announcement for week " & Range("I8").value & ", " & Range("T8").value & " - Confirmation required")
Call header.SetHeaderVal("HTML message")

'Set From
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("Principal", "Food Specials <mailto:Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk>")
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("ReplyTo", "Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk")
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("DisplaySent", "Food.Specials@Lidl.co.uk")

'To
Set header = body.CreateHeader("To")
Call header.SetHeaderVal(Range("Q" & i).value)


'Email Body
Call stream.WriteText("<HTML>")
Call stream.WriteText("<font size=""3"" color=""black"" face=""Arial"">")
Call stream.WriteText("<p>Good " & Range("A1").value & ",</p>")
Call stream.WriteText("<p>Please see attached an announcement of the spot buy promotion for week " & Range("I8").value & ", " & Range("T8").value & ".<br>Please check, sign and send this back to us within 24 hours in confirmation of this order. Please also inform us of when we can expect the samples.</p>")
Call stream.WriteText("<p>The details are as follows:</p>")

'Insert Range
Dim app As New Excel.Application
app.Visible = False
'open a workbook that has same name as the sheet name
Set WB3 = Workbooks.Open(Range("F" & i).value)
'select cell A1 on the target book
WB3.Range("A20:J30").SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)

Call stream.WriteText(rangetoHTML(rng))


Call stream.WriteText("<p><b>N.B.  A volume break down by RDC will follow 4/5 weeks prior to the promotion. Please note that this is your responsibility to ensure that the orders you receive from the individual depots match the allocation.</b></p>")
Call stream.WriteText("<p>We also need a completed Product Technical Data Sheet. Please complete this sheet and attach the completed sheet in your response.</p>")

'Attach file
Attachment = Range("F" & i).value
Set AttachME = doc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("attachment")
Set EmbedObj = AttachME.EmbedObject(1454, "", Attachment, "")


Call stream.WriteText("<BR><p>Please note the shelf life on delivery should be 75% of the shelf life on production.</p></br>")
'Signature
Call stream.WriteText("<BR><p>Kind regards / Mit freundlichen Grüßen,</p></br>")
Call stream.WriteText("<p><b>Lidl UK Food Specials Team</b></p>")

Call stream.WriteText("<table border=""0"">")
Call stream.WriteText("<tr>")
Call stream.WriteText("<td><img src=""http://www.lidl.co.uk/statics/lidl-uk/ds_img/layout/top_logo2016.jpg"" alt=""Mountain View""></td>")
Call stream.WriteText("<td><img src=""http://www.lidl.co.uk/statics/lidl-uk/ds_img/assets_x_x/BOQLOP_NEW%281%29.jpg"" alt=""Mountain View""></td>")
Call stream.WriteText("</tr>")
Call stream.WriteText("</table>")


Call stream.WriteText("</font>")
Call stream.WriteText("</body>")
Call stream.WriteText("</html>")

Call body.SetContentFromText(stream, "text/HTML;charset=UTF-8", ENC_IDENTITY_7BIT)

Call doc.Send(False)
session.ConvertMime = True ' Restore conversion - very important


'Clean Up the Object variables - Recover memory
    Set db = Nothing
    Set session = Nothing
    Set stream = Nothing
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set body = Nothing
    Set header = Nothing

    WB3.Close savechanges:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Email Code

j = j + 1

Next i
End With


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Success!" & vbNewLine & "Announcements have been sent."

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line returns the error?  Is it `Set WB3 = Workbooks.Open(Range("F" & i).value)`?  If so, have you verified that a workbook with the expected name exists?

Comment: @destination-data see updated question

Comment: `WB3.Sheets(1).Range`

Comment: @Slai Why don't you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Ralph was on my phone, and it was more of a hint towards the answer. A good answer would require explanation and reading the whole question, and I haven't had enough coffee yet :]

Answer (score 0):

WB3 is a Workbook object.  Workbooks don't support the [range property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  Instead, use a [worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx).

Example

```
WB3.Sheets(1).Range("A20:J30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

This line on it's own does not do anything.  If you want to select these cells call the select method:

```
WB3.Sheets(1).Range("A20:J30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

**EDIT**

Just noticed that @Slai had already identified the root cause, in the comments.

Comment: If you are using a comment by another user as an answer then you should mark this answer as a [community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat)

Comment: My comment is not the answer. I was hoping that someone would mention using the sheet name instead of number if there is more than one sheet. Seems like it should be `Set rng = WB3.Sheets("Sheet1").Range...` because of the line below it